# Importing moment into TypeScript project

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to use moment in my TypeScript project but when I use the line,

```
import moment from 'moment';
```

I get the error:

> 'node_modules/moment/moment' has no default export.

I have also tried,

```
import moment from 'moment/src/moment';
```

but then I get the error:

> 'Cannot find module moment/src/moment'.

Does anybody know a way of doing this? Thanks.

Comment: Does this work? `import moment = require('./bower_components/moment/src/moment');` ? Or `import moment = module('moment');` ?

Comment: See @Mr.Polywhirl's answer, "'node_modules/moment/moment' has no default export." means the script isn't a module

Comment: When I try import moment = module('moment') it gives the error "Cannot find namespace 'module'". Am I supposed to be including something for that? When I try the first piece of code (I am using node_modules) I get the error "Cannot find module '../node_modules/moment/src/moment'".

Comment: @Ozrix No it doesn't. It means that none of the exports are defined as default, so you need to tell it what you want to import. You can use * to import everything or curly braces to specify what you want.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The correct syntax is:

```
import * as moment from 'moment';
```

Comment: Awesome, That works and I get the intellisense for it in vscode. Is it possible to use a moment type in an interface? eg.

export interface Example {
    date: moment;
};

The above code gives me the error 'Cannot find name moment'.

Comment: You might need to use `moment.Moment`. E.g., `{date: moment.Moment;}`

Comment: be careful if you use babel on top of the above syntax, babel will prevent the function `moment()` from work as expected, due to how it associates with the spec.  You can add `"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true` to your `tsconfig.json` to allow `import moment from "moment";` to no longer throw an error.

Comment: @DavidD thanks! That `tsconfig.json` setting seems needed for rollup, as using `import * as moment from 'moment'` gives an error: `Cannot call a namespace ('moment')` otherwise

Comment: I have a Resharper error when using this way. `Cannot invoke an epxression whose type lacks a call signature`. Any Ideas?

Comment: Can anyone explain why `import * as moment from 'moment'` is the correct syntax for TS, but `import moment from 'moment'` is sufficient in JS?

Comment: This is not working with TS Version 3.6.2. even with "moduleResolution": "node", and "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true, in tsconfig

Answer (score 11):

I had the same issue and solved the problem in my project by adding `allowSyntheticDefaultImports`: true in `compilerOptions` in my `tsconfig.json` file and then I used the syntax

```
import moment from 'moment';
```

Reference: "https://momentjs.com/docs/#/use-it/typescript/"

Comment: You saved me some time, thankyou. This answer is the answer that works in all cases including angular libraries.

Comment: this should be the only correct answer, while most answers you can find in SO are just workarounds which are all clumsy, and I think Angular compiler can't be so dump.