# Why can't I use moment as an import in my TypeScript React native project?

Tags: typescript, react-native, momentjs

I want to use [MomentJS](http://momentjs.com) in my ReactNative component using TypeScript. My project is configured to pull in the [library's d.ts file](https://github.com/moment/moment/blob/develop/moment.d.ts) from the *node_modules* directory.

This is how I am importing the library and using it:

```
import * as moment from "moment";
const time = moment();
```

My typescript compiles but when I run the app ReactNative errors as so:

[image: ReactNative error]

This is my *tsconfig.json* file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "jsx": "react",
    "outDir": "build/",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true
  }
}
```

If I change my tsconfig 'target' to es5 I have problems with a number of other modules.

I think it is related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36893165/importing-moment-into-typescript-project) but I am doing as suggested in that question's answer.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39415661/why-cant-i-import-a-class-or-function-with-import-as-x-from-y for comments about invoking something you imported using `*`

Answer (score 1):

Quoting from [@DavidD's comment in the linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36893165/importing-moment-into-typescript-project?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment61356347_36893860):

> Be careful if you use babel on top of the above syntax, babel will prevent the function `moment()` from work as expected, due to how it associates with the spec. You can add `"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true` to your tsconfig.json to allow `import moment from "moment";` to no longer throw an error.

The underlying issue is that `moment` exports a function as the default, but when using Babel (as you are in React Native) this will get wrapped in an object by Babel.

I'm not sure if TypeScript is aware of this wrapping or if the definitions for momentjs need an update.