# Errors when using MomentJS in Angular Typescript library

Tags: angular, typescript, momentjs

I'm building an Angular (2+) component library using [jvandemo/generator-angular2-library](https://github.com/jvandemo/generator-angular2-library) as a starter, which uses [Rollup](https://github.com/rollup/rollup) as a module builder. The component I am creating in the library uses [MomentJS](https://momentjs.com/).

I've had various build issues with the inclusion of MomentJS.

I first used `import moment from 'moment';` to import moment into the component, but that produces the following error at build;

```
[17:26:28] Starting 'ngc'...
Error at /Users/chris/angular-library/.tmp/components/my-library/my-component.component.ts:6:8: Module '"/Users/chris/my-library/node_modules/moment/moment"' has no default export.
```

I found [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36893165/importing-moment-into-typescript-project) that said to use `import * as moment from 'moment';` however with that I get;

```
'moment' is imported by build/components/my-component.component.js, but could not be resolved – treating it as an external dependency

events.js:182
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
Error: Cannot call a namespace ('moment')
    at error (/Users/chris/angular-library/node_modules/rollup/dist/rollup.js:185:14)
```

As far as I can tell these are the only two options and I can't get either to work, what am I missing?

**Edit**

I've added [this issue](https://github.com/jvandemo/generator-angular2-library/issues/224) to the library's Github repo that contains minimalistic replication steps

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43257938/4298881, to be short, instead of "import moment from 'moment'", do "import * as moment from 'moment'"

Comment: @Surely as mentioned above doing that leads to `Error: Cannot call a namespace ('moment')`

Comment: are you using cli ?

Comment: @RahulSingh I'm using https://github.com/jvandemo/generator-angular2-library

Comment: sorry didn't read it carefully enough. I think this thread is quite similar to the issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39519823/using-rollup-for-angular-2s-aot-compiler-and-importing-moment-js

Comment: @Surely thanks yeah - I've tried that and still the same :(

Comment: Do you use moment in component while creating the variable, or you try to pass `moment()...` virtually in html template?

Comment: @Sergey moment is used exclusively in the component (`.ts`)

Comment: Could you upload your project to somewhere? I'd like to have a look at it.

Comment: @Sergey Thanks - I can't yet upload the project itself, but there are minimal replication steps in an issue I've just posted on Github that can be set up in a minute or two - https://github.com/jvandemo/generator-angular2-library/issues/224

Comment: @ChrisBrown have you installed moment with `save-dev` mark?

Comment: @Sergey yes, `npm install --save-dev moment` (although that shouldn't matter for running a build)

Comment: @ChrisBrown man. I, probably, found the root of the evil. It's the `save-dev` you should use it only for the things that are used only in developing and are not needed for app working. But, moment is used in app work. That means that it should be in "normal" dependencies, but not "dev".

Comment: @Sergey I tried it just in case, but whether moment is installed as dev or not doesn't affect whether the build runs successfully - you're correct I think it should be in `dependencies` not `devDependencies` but the error remains the same

Comment: To have a chance of reproducing your problem. Do I need to only install the `yo` and `generator-angular2-library`?

Comment: @Sergey to run the generator that's correct, `npm install -g yo generator-angular2-library` (instructions are in the readme at https://github.com/jvandemo/generator-angular2-library)

Comment: What version of moment are you using?

Comment: @PeterS The latest v2 (2.19.1)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The error is very clear and specific

> Error: Cannot call a namespace ('moment')
>       at error (/Users/chris/angular-library/node_modules/rollup/dist/rollup.js:185:14)

This is per the ES Module Specification.

That means the following is an invalid way to import moment, or anything you intend to call, because a module namespace object, such as that created by `* as ns` may not be called.

```
import * as moment from 'moment';
```

The correct form is the form that `ngc` is raising an error on

```
import moment from 'moment';
```

Firstly to make this work, you need to specify the `--allowSyntheticDefaultImports` flag.

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
  }
}
```

Assuming that `ngc` will recognize the option, you still have an additional problem to work out.

The flag above is for users of tools such as SystemJS or Webpack which perform the synthesis, allowing such code to typecheck.

As of TypeScript 2.7, you can now specify the `--esModuleInterop` flag to have the language provide the synthesis as part of the transpilation process.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true
  }
}
```

Note that if you are using a version of TypeScript prior to 2.7 *and* if you are compiling to CommonJS, AMD, or UMD modules (e.g. with `--module commonjs`) the correct import syntax is rather

```
import moment = require('moment');
```

The `import = require` syntax is a TypeScript specific construct, now largely unnecessary. It exists to acquire both the type *and* the value of the module exports of an AMD, CommonJS, or UMD module. The "and" is important because a `const`, `var`, or `let = require` invocation only creates a name in the value space not in the type space.

Comment: allowSyntheticDefaultImports will default to true when setting esModuleInterop=true so it is enough to set esModuleInterop=true

Comment: @EsbenSkovPedersen when I wrote this, there was a bug in TypeScript, I think it was fixed in 2.9 or 3.0, where the one didn't imply the other.

Comment: Good to know. I wrote it more as information to future readers.

Comment: I'll add a note

Comment: this saved lots of time

Answer (score 6):

To whoever finds this in 2018+, with Angular6 and current @angular/cli:

Today I ran into this and found [solution here](https://github.com/jvandemo/generator-angular2-library/issues/221).

```
import * as moment_ from 'moment';
const moment = moment_;
```

Now the library compiles OK for me.

Answer (score 1):

In the sample directive I had no problem compiling when I used the following:

```
import { Directive, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import * as moment from '../node_modules/moment/moment';
@Directive({
  selector: '[sampleDirective]'
})
export class SampleDirective {

  constructor(private el: ElementRef) {
    moment.isDate('test');
  }

}
```

The files are compiled from a build directory that is a sub-dir off the root.
You do get a further warn about "this", mentioned here:

https://github.com/rollup/rollup/issues/794

I need to say in the gulfile that the library is external:

```
  external: [
    '@angular/core',
    '@angular/common',
    'moment'
  ],
```

And from the github link, you should add a onwarn block to both rollup sections:
That is section 'rollup:umd' and 'rollup:fesm'

```
onwarn: function(warning) {
    // Skip certain warnings

    // should intercept ... but doesn't in some rollup versions
    if ( warning.code === 'THIS_IS_UNDEFINED' ) { return; }

    // console.warn everything else
    console.warn( warning.message );
},
```

Does that get you any further?

Comment: Thank you for looking - that works for me too when using `moment.isDate()` but it doesn't work for `moment()`, so sadly I'm at the same point.

For what it's worth, `import * as moment from 'moment';` works as well when only using `moment.isDate()`, so the path from `node_modules` isn't necessary there

Comment: Using import * as moment from 'moment'; should work fine.

If not, try npm uninstall moment, then npm i moment@latest, rm -rf node/modules and reinstall all your deps (npm i)