# "Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature" when importing jQuery in TypeScript

Tags: jquery, typescript

I'm currently evaluating TypeScript and have some problems when trying to import jQuery.

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';
const $el = $('#app');
```

report the following error:

```
src/log.ts:2:13 - error TS2349: Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type '{ default: JQueryStatic; ajaxSettings: AjaxSettings<any>; A
nimation: AnimationStatic; Callbacks: CallbacksStatic; cssHooks: CSSHooks; cssNumber: PlainObject<boolean>; Deferred: DeferredStatic; ... 62 more ...; when<TR1,
 UR1, VR1, TJ1 = any, UJ1 = any, VJ1 = any>(deferredT: TR1 | ... 1 more ... | Thenable<...>, defer...' has no compatible call signatures.

2 const $el = $('#app');
              ~~~~~~~~~

  src/log.ts:1:1
    1 import * as $ from 'jquery';
      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Type originates at this import. A namespace-style import cannot be called or constructed, and will cause a failure at runtime. Consider using a default impo
rt or import require here instead.
```

I have installed the jQuery module as follows:

```
npm i jquery --save
npm i @types/jquery --save-dev
```

and use the following generated `tsconfig.json` file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true
  }
}
```

I'm using the following versions:

```
{
  "name": "example",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "example",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jquery": "3.3.22",
    "typescript": "3.1.6",
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "jquery": "3.3.1"
  }
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: You may not call a module namespace object

Comment: @AluanHaddad Could you please elaborate?

Comment: This will explain it as well as explaining your question on the answer you received. https://stackoverflow.com/a/47007576/1915893

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As `@types/jquery` uses `export =`, importing it requires using `import =`.

Change

```ts
import * as $ from 'jquery';
```

to

```ts
import $ = require('jquery');
```

Comment: I'm not aware of this `import $ = require('jquery');` syntax. Could you explain where this syntax comes from or is documented?

Comment: It's TypeScript-specific syntax.
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#export--and-import--require

Comment: In my case I also needed to change in `tsconfig.json` the module declaration to `"module": "commonjs"`.

Comment: How can jquery be imported with esnext modules though?

Answer (score 1):

For "module": "esnext", below may help,

```
import jQuery from "jquery";
window.$ = window.jQuery = jQuery;
```