# Angular library import *

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, npm

So one of the modules that i use in my library is `sha256`. This has to be imported as such:

```
import sha256 from 'sha256';
```

Now I read on this SO question: 
[Errors when using MomentJS in Angular Typescript library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46876541/errors-when-using-momentjs-in-angular-typescript-library?rq=1)

That you need to do it differently when compiling:

So at first, I changed it to:

```
import * as sha256_ from 'sha256';
const sha256 = sha256_;
```

However these threw the same error:

```
ERROR: Cannot call a namespace ('sha256')
An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot call a namespace ('sha256')
```

Then i tried to edit my `tsconfig.json`:

```
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true
  }
```

However without any success.

Can anyone tell me how I can correctly build my library with such an import?

**Edit**

I also added it to the `compilerOptions`:

```
    "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../../out-tsc/lib",
    "target": "es2015",
    "declaration": true,
    "inlineSources": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "types": [],
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "es2018"
    ]
  },
```

**ng --version**

```
Angular CLI: 8.3.20
Node: 10.16.0
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 8.2.14
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router

Package                            Version
------------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect          0.803.20
@angular-devkit/build-angular      0.803.20
@angular-devkit/build-ng-packagr   0.803.20
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer    0.803.20
@angular-devkit/build-webpack      0.803.20
@angular-devkit/core               8.3.20
@angular-devkit/schematics         8.3.20
@angular/cli                       8.3.20
@ngtools/webpack                   8.3.20
@schematics/angular                8.3.20
@schematics/update                 0.803.20
ng-packagr                         5.7.1
rxjs                               6.4.0
typescript                         3.5.3
webpack                            4.39.2
```

Comment: at what point do you get that error. Im able to serve and build with `import * as sha256 from 'sha256';` and what bundler are you using?

Comment: @c_ogoo ive updated my question with my ng --version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this..

```
npm install --save @types/sha256
```

then

```
import sha256 from 'sha256';

or

import * as sha256_ from 'sha256';
```